# repainting with superg causes blanking.. netbeans

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have no idea what is the problem here, I just started coding I searched all over the internet and cannot find answers please don't make the answer sound complicated. thanks
I am trying to make a mario like game and it seems to be in the way, but soon I'll be better

```
int x, y;



public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(KeyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
            x--;
        }
        if(KeyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            x++;
        }
        if(KeyCode == e.VK_UP) {
            y--;
        }
        if(KeyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
            y++;
        }
    }
    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}



public Wesley() {
    addKeyListener(new AL());

    setTitle("Wesley and the interuption");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    x = 150;
    y = 150;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);

    repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Wesley();
}
```

Comment: I assume Weasly is extending from JFrame. You should avoid overriding paint generally, but especially of window based classes as they are not double buffered and this is what's creating flickering. Instead use something like JPanel and override its paintComponent

Answer (score 3):

- **Don't** `repaint()` in the `paint` method. You probably want to do it in one of your `keyXxx` methods.
- You're breaking the paint chain by **not** calling `super.paint(g);` in your `paint` method. So make sure you call it call it.

  ```
  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);
  }
  ```
- Also use `@Override` annotation so you know you are correctly overriding a method. This `KeyReleased` is not a valid override of the key released functionality. Your casing is wrong. So a key release will do nothing.

---

**Side Notes**

- Look into using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) with Swing apps for specific key functionality. You may have focus problems with `KeyListener`
- See [Performinf Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). It is preferred to paint on `JComponent` or `JPanel` and `@Override` `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent` and *not* `paint`.
- Run Swing apps from the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). See [Intial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- `setVisible` *after* `setLocationXxx`. I bet you're wondering why your ui flashes in the top left corner them moves to the center. *This* is why.